# How to remove a segment in vim Powerline?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm using [vim Powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline/), it comes by default with quite a few segments in the powerline. More than I want.

I'd like to remove several of the default ones. Specifically, the one that tells me my git branch, the file encoding, the source language, the line/col number, the one that says unix (probably line ends).

In the [docs](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline/blob/f0caee81697fd0021c82caee61265fdc3ae191de/doc/Powerline.txt#L272), they say you should be able to use Pl#Theme#RemoveSegment.

So I added `call Pl#Theme#RemoveSegment('fugitive')` to my ~/.vimrc, and then ran `:PowerlineClearCache` and reloaded the file, but the git branch is still there. Perhaps I'm getting the name wrong, I guessed that this is the one that enters my git branch based on the naming from [here](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline/blob/c4b72c5be57b165bb6a89d0b8a974fe62c0091d0/autoload/Powerline/Segments/fugitive.vim#L1).

If there's a way to reflect on some variable and see what segments are registered, that would be useful, but I can't tell if I'm getting the name wrong, or invoking the method incorrectly, or what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The theme list](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline/blob/c4b72c5be57b165bb6a89d0b8a974fe62c0091d0/autoload/Powerline/Themes/default.vim) suggests maybe the segment name should be `fugitive:branch` instead of `fugitive`. Kind of guessing, though.

Answer (score 2):

There may be more segments being added. I personally would suggest instead of using `Pl#Theme#RemoveSegment` do the following:

1. Copy `{path/to/powerline}/autoload/Powerline/Themes/default.vim` to `~/.vim/autoload/Powerline/Themes/my.vim`.
2. Replace in the first line of a new file `default` with `my`: it should look like

   ```
   let g:Powerline#Themes#my#theme = Pl#Theme#Create(
   ```
3. Add

   ```
   let g:Powerline_theme='my'
   ```
4. Remove all the stuff you don’t need, you will find plenty of it.

Comment: I tried this and nothing happened. I do think it's reading the my.vim theme, however, because it complained when I hadn't yet modified the line, '~/.vim/bundle/vim-powerline/autoload/Powerline/Themes`

Comment: @RosePerrone You are a bit late here. Powerline-vim is deprecated since November, 2012; and there is now a working replacement written almost purely in python (named just `powerline`). You may forgot to run `:PowerlineCacheClear`, `:PowerlineClearCache` or whatever it was called then (AFAIR applicable in case you first copied the theme, checked whether it works and only then started removing stuff).